# a custom marker for each type of place

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

i basically want to create a map which shows all the hotspots.

a bit like what this example does: [google maps example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search-pagination)

for example i'm going on a vacation and i want to know the nearest supermarket, nightclubs and bars. so i want to just type in a location and it shows me these spots with a custom marker.

i can figure most of this out myself but i can't seem to get multiple custom markers in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results returned by a placesSearch contain multiple properties for each [result](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#PlaceResult), one of them is the icon-property which contains the URL of the icon, e.g.:http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png [image]

Comment: first of all, thanks for taking the time to answer me! second, this certainly helped me further, but now it just takes the standard google icons. i made some custom ones i'd like to use. so i want a different url for each type.

Answer (score 0):

i've found the answer in a different example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers#customize_marker_icons_for_different_markers